# How to use WiFi in Opensuse 42.1

Tags: wifi, opensuse, networksetup

In superuser I did `ifconfig` and it detects my USB WiFi dongle. But I can't seem to work out how to set it up to connect to any networks.

I'm not new to Linux but it's the first time I've used Suse. Normally the network manager picks it up and I can connect straight away.

Have I missed some glaringly obvious menu setting or is there more to it?

Running gnome 3. WiFi dongle is a Realtek chipset.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to U&L , please edit by adding more information about your wifi USB through the command `lsusb`

Comment: Bus 006 device 002 ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Please do a `lsusb -v` and post the results pertaining to your network controller/adapter. And  what sort of wifi network are you trying to get on? If it has WPA or WPA2 protections you should be able to get on in bash using `wpa-supplicant`. On the other hand if your network has more advanced protections you'll want to use GNOME's network manager. You can find the basic information [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:WiFi#NetworkManager).

Do you have the wireless driver `r8712u`?
You haven't said how your network is protected. WPA or WEP?

Comment: Well I feel dumb.... I hadn't turned network manager on.. And I was trying to connect to a hidden network!!! Sorry!! But thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hehe. Did it work?

Comment: Yeah... I'd expected to see a list but it doesn't show anything... Plus I needed to update to use WPA... Just need to set up my gfx card now... Urgh... Thanks for your help though bud! Much appreciated and sorry to waste your time by being thick!! :D